# Pandas: Make function map partial Dict match

Tags: python, pandas

This function looks at strings in a pandas `DataFrame`. If the string contains a regular expression matching an entry in the dictionary, it passes on the captured string to other parts of the function and finally returns `statement`.

```
def f(value):
    f1 = lambda x: dictionary[regex.findall(x)[0]] if regex.findall(x)[0] in dictionary else ""
    match = f1(value)
    #Do stuff
    return statement
```

**Question**:

How can I make it accept *partial* matches, and replace the matching word, while keeping the rest of the string intact? Right now it only accepts *literal* matches.

**Goal**:

The string is `"BULL GOOGLE X3 VON"`. I would like `{"GOOG":` in the dictionary to be sufficient to transform the word to `:"Google"}`. The transformed string would be `"BULL Google X3 VON"`, and the function passes on `"Google"`.

Note: I want to continue using `dict` for the implementation because other parts of the program depends on it.

**Code:**

```
#DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL GOOGLE X3 VON", "BEAR TWITTER 12X S"], columns=["Name"])

#Dict
google = {"GOOG":"Google"}
twitter = {"TWITT":"Twitter"}
dictionary = goog.copy()
dictionary.update(twitter)

#Regex
regex = re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

#Function
def f(value):
    f1 = lambda x: dictionary[regex.findall(x)[0]] if regex.findall(x)[0] in dictionary else ""
    match = f1(value)
    #Do stuff
    return statement

#Map Function
df["Statement"] = df["Name"].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

**Ideas**:

If it's possible to modify the function directly to accept partial matches, that would be good.

Otherwise, a solution might be to first `replace` the matching word in the string – keeping the rest of the string intact – and then match the regex substring with the dictionary. These steps could happen in a temporary column so that the column `"Name"` is still in its original state for future use.

Comment: can't you just use `contains`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL GOOGLE X3 VON", "BEAR TWITTER 12X S"], columns ["Name"])

#Dict
google = {"GOOG":"Google"}
twitter = {"TWITT":"Twitter"}
dictionary = google.copy()
dictionary.update(twitter)

#Regex
regex = re.compile(r"\b((%s)\S*)\b" %"|".join(dictionary.keys()), re.I)

def dictionary_lookup(match):
    return dictionary[match.group(2)]

#Function
def f(value):
    match = dictionary[regex.search(value).group(2)]
    #Do stuff
    statement = regex.sub(dictionary_lookup, value)
    return statement

#Map Function
df["Statement"] = df["Name"].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

This will match any word that starts with one of the keys in the dictionary, assign the value of the match from the dictionary to the variable `match` and then return the original string with the matched word replaced.