# Replace parts of a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace parts of abbreviated addresses with the full address in a new csv but keep running into an error. How do I fix this?

1234 Edison Ln -----------> 1234 Edison Lane

4589 Stack Overflow Dr -----------> 4589 Stack Overflow Drive

```
import pandas as pd

mycsv = pd.read_csv('addressescsv')
mycsv['Address'] = str.replace({mycsv['Address']: {'Ln': 'Lane','Dr': 'Drive'}})

mycsv.to_csv('newAddressescsv', index=False)

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\movingalong.py", line 8, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 831, in __hash__
' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588316/pandas-applying-regex-to-replace-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [DataFrame.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address':['Ln', 'Dr', 'High']})
print df.replace({'Address' :{'Ln': 'Lane','Dr': 'Drive'}})
```

Output

```
       Address
0   Lane
1  Drive
2   High
```

Since you are looking for partial match you may want to try this

```
import re
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Address':['City Ln', 'New Dr', 'Ln']})
rep = {'Ln': 'Lane','Dr': 'Drive'}
regex = re.compile(r"\b((%s)\S*)\b" %"|".join(rep.keys()), re.I)

def dictionary_lookup(match):
    return rep[match.group(2)]

def ReplaceStr(value):
    NewValue = regex.sub(dictionary_lookup, value)
    return NewValue


df["New Address"] = df["Address"].map(lambda x:ReplaceStr(x))
print df
```

output

```
   Address New Address
0  City Ln   City Lane
1   New Dr   New Drive
2       Ln        Lane
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/32191354/6626530

Comment: Thanks, but the values are like this 1234 Edison Ln, 4785 Stack Overflow Dr. That is why I am using str.

Comment: I tried pd.DataFrame.replace({mycsv['Address']:......It still threw the same error.

Comment: Updated the answer